# Problema al generar PDF en DOMPDF

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo problemas al generar un pdf desde php con DOMPDF.

Este es el error que me de da

> Uncaught exception **'Dompdf\Exception' with message 'No block-level parent found.**

Y este es el código que utilizo:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
// instantiate and use the dompdf class

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$file=file_get_contents('resultados.php');
$dompdf->load_html($file);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('document.pdf');
echo $file;?>
```

He hecho un print de $file y he observado que file_get_contents() no procesa las variables. Creo que ahí puede estar el error. ¿Alguien conoce alguna manera para solventar esto?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar la ruta en la que se encuentra el fichero `resultados.php` y dónde está el fichero dónde estás ejecutando el DOMPDF?

Comment: Si. La ruta es en htdocs/ tanto para resultados.php como para el fichero donde ejecuto DOMPDF.

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta que las redirecciones estan bien y que el archivo .php lo que hace es renderizar la vista para crea la estructura podemos hacer esto:

```
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

ob_start(); //iniciamos un output buffer
require_once('resultados.php'); // llamamos el archivo que se supone contiene el html y dejamoso que se renderize
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());//y ponemos todo lo que se capturo con ob_start() para que sea capturado por DOMPDF

$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('document.pdf');
?>
```

Cualquier duda no dude en comentar